# Sitecore First Approach Can't see the component added to child placeholder

Tags: jss, dynamic-placeholder

We are working on POC to test new page addition through SitecoreFirst workflow. Have added a sample template and JSON rendering to my Sitecore app from the content editor and created a route to host a page based on the new template. But when adding the rendering to the placeholders(child placeholders) the JSS layout service call isn't returning the data for that component\rendering.
I know JSS has dynamic placeholders implementation but then I can't add components through Experience editor as ExpEditor is broken currently. I tried giving a UID like this in content editor
\main\content-{UID}-0 as a placeholder name but it's not working. Can't see any data in the final JSS call.

Any clue to make this work?

Comment: Have you added your component in "Allowed Controls" in placeholder.

Comment: Yes. I've added it to Allowed Controls as well.

Comment: Got it resolved. Was taking UID from 'Renderings' field. It should be from FinalRenderings in my case. All good.